# Read PDF form data

Tags: php, parsing, pdf, post, submit

I would like to create a PDF form that submits its data by POST to a PHP page. I want PHP to be able to read the data in the fields using `$_POST[]`

Is this possible?

I created a PDF in Acrobat Pro and put a button at the bottom. The action is set to "submit a form" and I have set the export format to HTML.

In the PHP file which the form submits to, running `print_r($_POST);` simply gives me an empty array.

How do I send/access the data via `POST` please?

Thanks :)

Comment: This is no answer but I wouldn't recommend pdf for the application.  iPads etc...

Comment: Can you find out how it's done on this PDF, http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_014.pdf

Comment: Are you sure that you exported to HTML? If you did correct, you have to use the function fopen to read HTML.

Comment: Thanks. Looking at the manual for fopen I have to specify a file name. How would I know this when the data is being submitted to my script?